# rust - iterate over enum variants with limit

Tags: rust

Below are simplified example of my codes:

```
#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum Period {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
}
...
#[test]
fn enum_loop_test() {
   for period in Period::iter() {
       println!("{:?}", period);
   }
}
```

with above I will get the whole sets of `Period` printed out.
But what if I only want partial of it?

I want to have a random generate a number to get just partial of the set like `[ A, B, C]` or `[ A, B, C, D, E]`, randomly. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is `EnumIter`? Where did it come from?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can generate a random number from 1 to length of `Period` and only iterate till that point

Comment: And what *exactly* you mean by generate randomly a part of it? Do you want random first n elements?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze `EnumIter` if a crate for iterate the enum. https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.EnumIter.html

Comment: @MayRestinPeace can you give example? I am rather new to Rust so not sure how to do that.

Comment: @sooon Look at [Iterator::take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rand` crate to get your random count, and `take` that many elements from your iterator:

```rust
use strum::IntoEnumIterator;
use strum_macros::EnumIter;
use rand::{self, Rng};

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum Period {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
}

fn main() {
    let max = Period::iter().count();
    let n = rand::thread_rng().gen::<usize>() % max;

    for period in Period::iter().take(n) {
        println!("{:?}", period);
    }
}
```

Note that this may return an iterator with no elements, and you would want to adjust how `n` is calculated if that is undesirable.